# implicitly finding the template variable typename

Tags: c++, c++11

I have these functions:

```
template<class Route, bool enabled=true>
inline void addRoute() {
    if(!enabled) return;       
    routes.push_back(Route({}, {}));
}

template<class Route, bool enabled=true, class... Args>
inline void addRoute(Args&&... args, std::vector<LogLevel>&& levels_ = {},
                 std::vector<String>&& categories_={}) {
    if(!enabled) return;
    if(!removeLowerLevels(levels_)) return; 
    routes.push_back(Route(std::forward<Args>(args)..., levels_, categories_));
}
```

This function is supposed to pass the "main" parameters (levels_ and categories_ of the any Route class); if there are any additional parameters in one of the derived classes, it can also be passed to the route. I want this function to work in multiple ways:

```
//1. takes no additional arguments
addRoute<ConsoleLogRoute, DEBUG>({LogLevel::Notice}, {"system"});
//2. Takes no additional or main arguments
addRoute<SomeCustomLogRoute>();
//3. Takes additional arguments but no main arguments
addROute<HtmlLogRoute>("textFile.html", HtmlLogRoute::MakeBulletLists);
//4. Takes any amount of additional arguments
addRoute<FileLogRoute>("filename.log", {LogLevel::Info}, {"application"});
```

1 and 2 works as expected. But 3 and 4 fails to compile:

`Error: Candidate function requires at most 2 arguments, but X were provided.` (X being 3 or 4)

I fix this error by providing the variables for the `Args`:

```
addRoute<FileLogRoute, true, String>("filename.log", {LogLevel::Info}, {"application"});
```

My question is:

What can I do to not to explicitly write the variable typename? Like in this [printf example](http://ideone.com/XIlKFW) (taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template)).

Comment: `std::tuple` has a similar problem when you want to pass an allocator. It is solved in the Standard library by passing a tag, see the overloads taking a `std::allocator_arg_t` in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple

Comment: Can you put the 'additional arguments' in front?  That is by far the easiest way.

Comment: Note that it *can* be solved the way you are doing it.  I am just leery about the solution being worth the price.

Comment: @Yakk after a while, I realized I am better off using good old pointer/reference passing :)

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at an even simpler example:

```
  // declare something to call, just for filler.
int sum(int i) { return i ; }
template <class T, class... A> int sum(T v, A&&... vs) { return v + sum( vs... ) ; }

template < class... A >
  int process( A&&... a, int val )  
{   
  return sum( val, a... ) ;  
}

int main()
{   
  int i ;  

  i= process( 10) ;  
  i= process( 10, 1 ) ;   // fail

  return 0 ;  
}
```

By putting the argument `int val` after the variatic template parameters, both GCC and Clang set the parameter list for `A&&` to zero.  If you swap positions, it works fine.  So basically `A&&...` is non-greedy, and if you put any other parameters after it, it defaults to nothing.

As you discovered, by explicitly declaring the types, it will work, so in this case

```
i= process<int>( 10, 1 )
```

would work.

Comment: Yeah but the point was to not explicitly declare the type. I am not doing it for performance or anything. Just solely for the simplicity.